# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types: Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

In our project we are using the following nuget package:

**Microsoft.SqlServer.Types**

Everything has worked fine until recently without me obviously changing anything important the ASP.NET application breaks when starting with following exception:

> Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 5)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: Error loading msvcr120.dll
>   (ErrorCode: 5)

The stacktrace:

> [Exception: Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 5)]
>   SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssembly(String nativeBinaryPath,
>   String assemblyName) in
>   E:\Dev\Jacobo\ServerApi\SqlServerTypes\Loader.cs:43
>   SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies(String
>   rootApplicationPath) in
>   E:\Dev\Jacobo\ServerApi\SqlServerTypes\Loader.cs:28
>   Jacobo.ServerApi.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in
>   E:\Dev\Jacobo\ServerApi\Global.asax.cs:26
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode:
>   5)]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +529
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +185
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +421
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +359
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode:
>   5)]    System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +534    System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +117
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +726

The application breaks in following method:

```
private static void LoadNativeAssembly(string nativeBinaryPath, string assemblyName)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(nativeBinaryPath, assemblyName);
            var ptr = LoadLibrary(path);
            if (ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format(
                    "Error loading {0} (ErrorCode: {1})",
                    assemblyName,
                    Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            }
        }
```

Which is part of **loader.cs** which is a part of the SqlServerTypes nuget package.

I checked the bin folder and located the SqlServerTypes assemblies existing there. I am really unsure what has gone wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error code 5 I would say the identity the web app is running doesn't have access to the path that the DLL is located.

The error code 5 means: ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.
Please check that the identity has permissions to that folder/file.

Answer (score 11):

I encountered this issue today. The fix I needed to implement was to ensure the SQL Server types files were part of my project so they would be produced in the publish output:

[image: DLLs in solution explorer]

Just ensure that `Copy to Output Directory` is set for each of the relevant DLL files. If you do not see them in your solution explorer, you may need to select to show all files and then right click them to `Include in Project`.

[image: Added unreferenced files in solution explorer]

Comment: Indeed this was the case. I had to copy the libs from the Packages folder as they were not in the directory as you have shown, but otherwise spot on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved it by giving the `IIS_IUSRS` user group permissions to the project directory.

This can be done by going into the folder's properties, then under the security tab, click **Edit** then **Add**, type **`IIS_IUSRS`** and click **OK**